# C# 8.0 nullable and generics

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

Would like to implement a method like the following by using the C#8.0 Nullable Check feature:

```cs
public static T Min<T>(IEnumerable<T> objects) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    bool first = true;
    T result = default; // <---- CS8653

    foreach (var obj in objects)
    {
        // Bla Bla
    }

    return result;
}
```

I get an error at the marked line (fourth line):

> MathHelper.cs(129,24,129,31): warning CS8653: Ein Standardausdruck führt einen NULL-Wert ein, wenn "T" ein Verweistyp ist, der keine NULL-Werte zulässt.

English translation: A default value introduces a null value, if T is a reference type which does not allow null values...

But now the challenge:

1) I'd like to have this function for 'structs' and for 'classes', so introducing "where class" or "where struct" is not an option.

2) **T? result = default** givers an error:

> CS8627    Ein Nullable-Typparameter muss als Werttyp oder als Nicht-Nullable-Verweistyp bekannt sein. Sie sollten eine class-, struct- oder eine Typeinschränkung hinzufügen. BurnSystems

3) **T! result = default** also does not work..,..

Anybody having an idea how to get the nullable check feature running for generic functions which allow a reference and value type while the reference value may be null....

---

EDIT: 
The project file:

```cs
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>8</LangVersion>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: with the given code, I don't get this warning   (.NET Core 3 / C# 8 )

Comment: I think you can do `T? result = default` if you add the `notnull` constraint.

Comment: https://ibb.co/gTpq4xb - Here, the screenshot... 

@juharr: 
> public static T Min<T>(IEnumerable<T> objects) where T : IComparable<T>, notnull
gives an error at 'notnull' - "Cannot resolve symbol 'notnull'"

Comment: also, if the result of this is going to be a "Min" getting default is not going to be useful

Comment: my project targets ```<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>``` so maybe something about targeting std2.0 is the problem

Comment: What does `CS8627 Ein Nullable-Typparameter muss als Werttyp oder als Nicht-Nullable-Verweistyp bekannt sein. Sie sollten eine class-, struct- oder eine Typeinschränkung hinzufügen. BurnSystems` translate to in English?

Comment: Hi, just trying netstandard2.1 since I would like to use the library also for .Net Framework legacy application using the library... Just a test baloon... 
But this also means that I have to switch to .Net Framework 4.8 for the referencing applications.

Comment: **default!** Was never aware of this. Looks a bit strange and creates struggle in the methods using the Min-Function (since they can't see that the return value might be null)

Thanks... 

Using .Net Framework 2.1 did not help a lot. `notnull` does not work. 

@mjwills: The translation means: That the nullable type parameter shall be known as value or as non-nullable reference value... I should add a where struct or where class.

Comment: Do you really need to initialize that temporary result variable with the default value ?  Why don't you initialize it with the first item of the collection ?  (And when the collection does not contain any items, I think it is appropriate to throw an exception).

Comment: Hi, this was just an example. I could find another method, where your proposal might not be appropriate... The method should have been resilient against empty enumerations. It was more about understanding nullables and reference/value generics... I'm a bit surprised that Microsoft does not have a clearer definition for default.

Comment: Can you use the `class?` constraint: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/nullable-reference-types#generics